# HttpContext.User.Identity doesn't work in release mode

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to use HttpContext.User.Identity and it works perfectly in Debug but when I publish it doesn't identify Windows User.

This is `launchsetting.json` file

```
{   "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53960/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }   },   "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DataManager": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53961/"
    }   } }
```

I'm currently using .net core 2.0

Upd: this is my `appsettings.json` file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "GlossaryConnection": "██████████████",
    "EmployeeConnection": "██████████████"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"?
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: Are you running the application via Visual Studio, in Release mode? Because, that's not really what lauchSettings.json was meant to support... **appSettings.json** on the other hand, was meant for supporting running the application outside of VS.

Comment: Upd: add appsettings.json

Comment: Where you deploy your application? IIS? If the application host on IIS, please check the IIS Authentication configuration (Open IIS, select the website, double click the Authentication, and check the [authentication configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWqzh.png)), make sure the Windows Authentication is Enabled and Anonymous Authentication is Disabled status.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Can you duplicate this as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@Zhi Lv` All I nedded is to check the IIS Authentication configuration (Open IIS, select the website, double click the Authentication, and check the authentication configuration), make sure the Windows Authentication is Enabled and Anonymous Authentication is Disabled status